# How to create a pure organization account on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-organizations

As GitHub user I can create an organization. But **can I also create an organization account without creating a user?**

The background is: I want to create an organization account for a company, but don't want to create a new fake user account, that then would create it. Is it possible to cerate an organistion (user) account without creating a "normal" user (account) before?